# Subviews not moving properly

Tags: ios, swift

I am swiping cards left/right like Tinder app. When I swipe left/right card view than subview moving weirdly. I am using ZLSwipeableViewSwift library.

```
func loadFront(){

    if frontView == nil {
        frontView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardFront", owner: self, options: nil).first as? CardFront
        self.addSubview(frontView!)



        frontView?.frame = self.bounds
        frontView?.hidden = false
    }
}
```

[image: Text going outside]

Comment: Have you tried         frontView?.boundes = self.bounds

Comment: yes but same result